# Any way to further reduce the number of lines of code?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm looking for ways to reduce the number of lines of code for this function. Any help is appreciated!

```
private bool CanSubmitPackage ( object obj )
    {
        // ---- Checks if the package contains any files to be submitted ----
        if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files != null )
        {
            if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files.Count > 0 )
                if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform != "" )
                    if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath != "" )
                        if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize != "" )
                            if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy != "" )
                                return true;
                            else
                                return false;
                        else
                            return false;
                    else
                        return false;
                else
                    return false;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files?.Count > 0
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize) 
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy));
```

Comment: This is really short! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can make it shorter and readable by using `&&` operator and `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method:

```
return ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files != null 
&& _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files.Count > 0 
&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform)
&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath)
&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize)
&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy));
```

If you're using `c#6+`, then you can go further (just a little bit) and use **[Expression Bodied method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)**:

```
private bool CanSubmitPackage () => //I'm not sure about object obj argument
    ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files != null 
    && _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files.Count > 0 
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy));
```

If you are going after making your code text shorted, you can declare a short named variable and use that instead of `_selectedWorkspace.Package`:

```
var p = _selectedWorkspace.Package;
return (p.Files?.Count > 0
       && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Platform)
       && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.PackagePath)
       && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.PackageSize)
       && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.SubmittedBy));;
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructive contribution! I will replace the && to || because I need to check either one of the properties is null/empty and not all properties are null/empty. I will take this as answer to my objective here, to "reduce the number of lines of code". Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it

**Update**

```
return ( _selectedWorkspace != null
    && _selectedWorkspace.Package != null
    && _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files != null 
    && _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files.Count > 0 
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize)
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy));
```

**Old Ans**

```
return ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files != null 
    && _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files.Count > 0 
    && ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform != "" )
    && ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath != "" )
    && ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize != "" )
    && ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy != "" ));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to do it

```
private bool CanSubmitPackage(object obj)
        {
            // ---- Checks if the package contains any files to be submitted ----
            if (_selectedWorkspace.Package.Files == null) return false; 
            if (_selectedWorkspace.Package.Files.Count <= 0) return false;
            if (_selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform == null && _selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform == "") return false; 
            if (_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath == null && _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath == "") return false;
            if (_selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize != _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize != "")
                return _selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy != "";

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer @xneg's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53096740/10588170), however, you could also drop all 'else' Statements and replace them with a single return statement after the 'if'-block.
Make sure to use string.IsNullOrEmpty(_str) in future, or you have to use && instead of ||, otherwise you will get an Exception because you are checking if _str is empty if it is null and if it is not null, you are not checking the content of _str at all. I am pretty sure that that's not what you wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe split the conditions, for example:

```
public bool HasFile
{
   get { return _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files != null && _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files.Count > 0; }
}

public bool HasPlatform
{
   get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform); }
}

// Do that for all conditions
```

And then you can write your final `if` like this:

```
bool result = HasFile && HasPlatform && …
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep it largely the same, as the return for all of your IF statements failing is `false`, you only need to include it once. If any of your current checks fail, it won't be able to execute "return true", so you can just have one final return statement like this:

```
private bool CanSubmitPackage ( object obj )
{
    // ---- Checks if the package contains any files to be submitted ----
    if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files != null )
        if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Files.Count > 0 )
            if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.Platform != "" )
                if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackagePath != "" )
                    if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.PackageSize != "" )
                        if ( _selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy != null || _selectedWorkspace.Package.SubmittedBy != "" )
                            return true;

    // One of the above checks failed, that's why we're running this line
    return false;
}
```

I also prefer @xneg, @SeM, or @Mihir Dave's approach (as they're all basically the same answer), but it does come down to what you find most comfortable / readable. I would definitely use the method `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to simplify your if statements however.

Additionally, what the `?` does in xneg's answer: `_selectedWorkspace.Package.Files?.Count` is say "If Files is not null, retrieve Files.Count, otherwise return `null`. Then in C# a statement like, `null > 0` always returns `false`.